# maximal subgroup of a group

Tags: group-theory

This may be a very trivial question, but I cannot find a definite "yes" or "no" answer in my textbook:

If $M \subsetneq G$ is a maximal subgroup of a group $G$, then since $M \lhd \textbf{N}_{G}(M)$ (the normalizer of $M$ in $G$), we must have, by the requirement of proper containment, $\textbf{N}_{G}(M) = G$.

Does that not mean that every maximal subgroup $M \subsetneq G$ is automatically normal in $G$?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless $G$ is assumed nilpotent, there is no reason why $M$ should be properly contained in $N_G(M)$.

Comment: But, since $M$ is normal in its normalizer, which is a subgroup of $G$, does that not make $M \lhd G$ automatically? How about in finite groups?

Comment: $M$ being maximal only gives you $N_G(M) = M$ or $N_G(M) = G$.

Comment: Any finite group has maximal subgroups, so clearly if the group is simple, any maximal subgroup will be self-normalizing

Comment: Yup, I got it now. Thank you, Kildetoft and Martini.

Comment: As Tobias says though, any maximal subgroup in a nilpotent group is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that $G$ satisfies the normalizer condition ($H \lneqq G$ implies $H \lneqq N_G(H)$) then it is true that maximal subgroups are normal. Indeed, if $M$ is a maximal subgroup, then either $M = N_G(M)$ or $M$ is a normal subgroup.

In general it is possible that a maximal subgroup is self-normalizing. The smallest example is given by the symmetric group $S_3$, where subgroups of order $2$ are maximal but not normal.